# Remove trailing '/' from the end of URL

Tags: javascript, html, function, onload

So I have the following bit of code which works to some extent.

```
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;

var sanitized = url
    .replace(/^https\:\/\//, '') // remove the leading http:// (temporarily)
    .replace(/\/+/g, '/')       // replace consecutive slashes with a single slash
    .replace(/\/+$/, '');       // remove trailing slashes

url = 'https://' + sanitized;

window.onload = function urlChange(){
    location.replace(url);
}
```

The only issue is that once the url gets changed the page keeps reloading as if I have an infinite loop going on.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You should have  a check if original URL is fine. If not, clean it and replace it. Currently you are setting always. Hence infinite reload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the url is actually changed, and only replace their location if it has been changed. You should also probably use `window.url` rather than manually constructing it from the protocol, host and pathname.

```
var sanitized = window.url
                      .replace(/^https\:\/\//, '') // remove the leading http:// (temporarily)
                      .replace(/\/+/g, '/') // replace consecutive slashes with a single slash
                      .replace(/\/+$/, ''); // remove trailing slashes

sanitized = 'https://' + sanitized; // add https to the front

window.onload = function urlChange() {
    if (window.url !== sanitized) {
        location.replace(sanitized);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To update the url without actually updating the `location` (which results in reloading the browser), you may use the html5 [pushState](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/) event:

```
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;

var sanitized = url
    .replace(/^https\:\/\//, '') // remove the leading http:// (temporarily)
    .replace(/\/+/g, '/')       // replace consecutive slashes with a single slash
    .replace(/\/+$/, '');       // remove trailing slashes

url = 'https://' + sanitized;

window.onload = function urlChange(){
    window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the "/" from the url only if exist at the end using endsWith() in the string.
You could check if the "/" exist at the end of hash or pathname and remove it
then redirect to wanted page without the "/" at end.

Also you need to skip homepage as it will always be "/" on the pathname

```
var url_view = window.location.href;
var url_path = window.location.pathname;
var url_hash = window.location.hash;
if(url_path.endsWith("/") || url_hash.endsWith("/")) {
    //Skip Home Page
    if(url_path !== "/"){
      url_view = url_view.slice(0,-1);
      window.location.replace(url_view);
    }
}
```